# Air brick in old Toronto home?

Tags: vent, old-house

We have a house that was built in 1937 in Toronto. It is a double brick design. On one of the outside walls, I can see what appears to be a single-brick-sized vent and I don't know what its function is.

At first I thought it may be an air brick but after further investigation, I found that there is what looks like a cleanout on the inside wall in the same place as the vent is on the outside wall.  Additionally, there seems to be a 1" pipe that runs down to the basement from the vent The pipe is capped in the basement. The previous owner said he capped it because water was coming into the basement via this pipe.  I also know that there was a washer and dryer in the same area in the basement in this location previously.

Does anyone know what this vent, cleanout, and pipe may be for? It seems too small a diameter for a dryer vent.

**EDIT**: Brother suggested it may be a vent for an old oil tank. Possible?

**EDIT:** Added annotated image.
[image: Vent pictures]

**EDIT:**

Added individual photos.
[image: The vent]
[image: Possibly the cleanout]
[image: The end of the pipe in the basement that I suspect is connected to the vent]
Cheers!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A picture of either end would be really helpful.

Comment: Depending on the size and construction of the vent, possible uses could have been a clothes dryer vent or a chimney stack for a wall hung heater. The 1" pipe could have been for a water line to the outside , a gas line or gas regulator vent line or a pressure relief dump line.

Comment: @DanielGriscom: Finally added an image to my post.

Comment: @d.george If this is a gas regulator vent line or a pressure relief dump line, would the tank that this was connected to have to have been near this line? The furnace room is on the other side of the house from where this vent is.

Comment: Very interesting! How do you know the basement pipe is connected to that vent? What does the writing on the basement pipe end say? Is that a cap that blocks it, or just a flange with a through-hole in the middle?

Comment: @DanielGriscom: At this point, I only suspect that it is connected because I took some measurements and the pipe is in the exact same spot as the vent. The cap was put on there by the previous owner. He said that he had a small amount of water leak into the basement through the pipe so he placed the cap on it. I'll have to take a better look at it to tell you what the writing says.

Comment: This gets more and more interesting. Try popping that cap and blowing/talking into it while a friend listens to the outside vent. Try removing the outside vent cap; if it does come off, then show what's inside. (BTW, it's cool that you composed and labeled the photos, but giving separate photos with text captions is actually better, so we can zoom in and see details.)

Comment: @DanielGriscom I added the individual photos. Will post more info once I investigate further.